# AWS s3 show node js file on static URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to deploy a Browser View of the UI via an s3 bucket I am auto deploying through github and deploy bot to a s3 bucket.

My Local environment auto deploys the server.js file to run in the browser. How do I enable to same on using AWS to ensure that the files are delivered in a browser as I am trying to set up a staging environment for my client.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What does node.js have to do with serving a js file to the browser via S3?